# user defined methods compiler errors

Tags: java, compiler-errors, user-defined

Okay, apologies now if you do not like my indentations (I'm a beginner)..

I can't get this code to compile. 
The assignment is to write two user defined methods, one (a boolean) that determines if a letter is a vowel, the other that changes a user inputted int (ex: 12345) to the reverse (54321)
I am having such a hard time with this code. 
Suggestions and tips would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATED: New code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InClassModule8
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a letter: ");
    String letter = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
    int digit = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println(isVowel(letter));
    System.out.println("The reversed digits are: " + reverseDigit(digit));
    }
}

  private static boolean isVowel(String line) 
  {
    line = (line != null) ? line.trim() : "";
    if (line.length() == 1) {
        switch (Character.toUpperCase(line.charAt(0))) 
        {
        case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
            return true;
        }

    return false;
    }

  private static String reverseDigit(int val) 
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(val));
    return sb.reverse().toString();
  }
```

Errors right now:

> 6 errors found: File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module
>   3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 16] Error:
>   /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module
>   4/In_Class_Module_8.java:16: class, interface, or enum expected File:
>   /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module
>   4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 19] Error:
>   /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module
>   4/In_Class_Module_8.java:19: class, interface, or enum expected File:
>   /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module
>   4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 24] Error:
>   /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module
>   4/In_Class_Module_8.java:24: class, interface, or enum expected File:
>   /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module
>   4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 27] Error:
>   /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module
>   4/In_Class_Module_8.java:27: class, interface, or enum expected File:
>   /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module
>   4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 32] Error:
>   /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module
>   4/In_Class_Module_8.java:32: class, interface, or enum expected File:
>   /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module
>   4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 33] Error:
>   /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module
>   4/In_Class_Module_8.java:33: class, interface, or enum expected

Comment: Count your parenthesis and curly braces, and make sure all match up. Make sure that your return statements are in the right location (one method definitely has a misplaced return statement).

Comment: I think this should be `if( letter = A|| .....` some thing like `"A".equalsIgnoreCase(letter)`???

Comment: this is In_Class_Module_8 C naming style not Java. you should hava **InClassModule8**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main()` has some extra calls. I think you just wanted something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a letter: ");
    String letter = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
    int digit = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println(isVowel(letter));
    System.out.println("The reversed digits are: " + reverseDigit(digit));
}
```

To test if it's a vowel, let's trim the output and switch on the uppercase character like -

```
private static boolean isVowel(String line) {
    line = (line != null) ? line.trim() : "";
    if (line.length() == 1) {
        switch (Character.toUpperCase(line.charAt(0))) {
        case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

To reverse the number, convert it to a `String` add it to a `StringBuilder` and then `reverse()` that,

```
private static String reverseDigit(int val) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(val));
    return sb.reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: Okay, now for the reverse the number section, does your code replace my code completely, or add to it.

Comment: Replace completely. I just implemented it the easiest way I knew how (which could be one line `return new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(val)).reverse().toString();`)

Comment: Okay, I have some new errors now: with the isVowel line: class, interface, enum expected

Comment: I posted updated code, still not compiling. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra brace in `reverseDigits()`

```
    }
    return number;
    }
  }
```

The one after `return number;` is one too many.

Comment: I took that out and still have 6 "class, interface, or enum expected " errors

Comment: You have a multitude of mismatched braces. The closing brace right after main() is breaking you up. `isVowel()` doe not have a closing brace. Please find an editor that can highlight the "other' brace and check your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an extra curly brace at line 48. Please remove that.

Also at line 33, the code `return status` should come after the closing `else` statement.

```
else 
{
  status = false;
}
return status;
```